# dbus-1.0/dbus/dbus.h:29:10: fatal error: 'dbus/dbus-arch-deps.h' file not found

Tags: dbus, google-chrome-os

I am using dbus in my programme, but when i include 
`#include <dbus-1.0/dbus/dbus.h>`

I am getting error :
`dbus-1.0/dbus/dbus.h:29:10: fatal error: 'dbus/dbus-arch-deps.h' file not found`

In the folder dbus there is no `dbus-arch-deps.h` file.

I can see this file in a folder `lib64/dbus-1.0/include/dbus/dbus-arch-deps.h`

Can any one please help me to compile this?
Or any suggestion, as I am stuck badly here.

Comment: finally i solved the problem, by adding `-I/usr/lib64/dbus-1.0/include/` in cflags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since I didnt get the answer from any one, but I finally solved the issue.
So would like to post the solution if some one faces similar problem.

I solved the problem, by adding `-I/usr/lib64/dbus-1.0/include/` in cflags.

Comment: A better solution would be to use the following to compile: `$CC dbus-example.c $(pkg-config --libs --cflags dbus-1)`

Answer (score 1):

Late answer. However This may be helpful for somebody who's working on WSL (Windows sub system ) with ubuntu (18.04 lts).

The includ folders are

- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include
- /usr/include/dbus-1.0

Also Link with :

- -ldbus-1

In case if you find nothing in there try : sudo apt-get install dbus-x11

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that dbus needs two different include paths. In any case, the best approach is to use pkg-config here. The pkg-config file dbus-1.pc, in fact, includes these cflags:

```
Cflags: -I${includedir}/dbus-1.0 -I${libdir}/dbus-1.0/include
```

So, on Manjaro for instance, you'd get:

```
pkg-config --cflags dbus-1
-I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/dbus-1.0/include
```

On an arm debian you'd get:

```
pkg-config --cflags dbus-1
-I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/dbus-1.0/include
```

Answer (score 0):

As it's been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64136880/14628838), if you're using CMake, just add

```
target_include_directories(ProjectName PRIVATE /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include/ /usr/include/dbus-1.0/)
target_link_libraries(ProjectName PRIVATE dbus-1)
```

lines after the `add_executable` line, where ProjectName - is the name of your project

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include/dbus/dbus-arch-deps.h /usr/include/dbus-1.0/dbus/.
```